# Concatenate a variable inside a jquery return literal variable name instead

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, laravel

Hello I just started learning about laravel and backend development in general, and currently working on a project to build a crud system, i'm trying to update the image row from the datatable inside an ajax function by concatenate the variable that hold the image name as a parameter to my api and wrapped it all in a string, like so:

```
var newRow = $datatable.row.add([data.id, data.name, "<img id='pic' src='{{url('api/img',['foldername',"+data.img+"])}}' style='width:500; height:500'/>"]).draw().node()
```

I expect the output on the image columns to be something like :

```
<img id='pic' src='http://localhost:8000/api/img/foldername/imagename.jpg' style='width:500; height:500'/>
```

but instead i got :

```
<img id='pic' src='http://localhost:8000/api/img/foldername/%2Bdata.img%2B' style='width:500; height:500 />
```

My api route looks something like :

```
Route::get('image/{foldername}/{filename}','ImageController@getImage');
```

Does anyone have any explanation to this problem? what did i do wrong here?

Comment: try changing it to `'"+data.img+"'`

Comment: @Tushar it turns into `<img id='pic' src='localhost:8000/api/img/foldername/%2A%2Bdata.img%2B%2A' style='width:500; height:500 />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things (I'm assuming this is in a blade file):

1) You have an extra closing square bracket `]` in the `url()` helper method. Both the folder and the filename should be inside the array, like this. You also need to be careful about alternating single and double quotes.

```
url('api/img', ['foldername', 'filename'])
```

2) The blade PHP which renders the url is running on the server before the javascript runs in the browser. Since the JS gives `data.img` its value, PHP doesn't know what that is supposed to be, and that's why it is interpreting it as the string "+data.img+" with escaped plus characters for the URL (`%2b`).

Something you could do instead is make a url with placeholders in PHP, then replace the placeholders with real values in JS when you know what they are.

```
// This will allow blade to create the url with placeholders in PHP, and it will be interpreted 
// as a string literal in JS and assigned to the variable placeholderUrl
var placeholderUrl = "{{ url('api/img', ['foldername', 'filename']) }}";

// Then you can use JS to replace the value in the url
var realUrl = placeholderUrl.replace('filename', data.img);

// Then use the real URL to create the img tag. Notice the alternating single and double quotes
var imgTag = '<img id="pic" src="' + realUrl + '" style="width:500; height:500" />';

// And finally, use the img tag when you add the row
var newRow = $datatable.row.add([data.id, data.name, imgTag]).draw().node();
```

Comment: When i try making the 'placeholderUrl', the script reads the string as a direct call to the api, so it returns something like `unexpected 'foldername'` as an error

Comment: What i did so far was, i make the blade php string url at the controller and concate the image name there and return it inside the json response as `data.image`, it kinda works, but when i add it to the datatable, the php blade string doesnt load and it returns as follow instead 
`<img id="pic" src="{{url('api/image',['foldername', 'filename'])}}" style="width:500; height:500"/>`

Comment: alright i figure it out, replace the placeholder on the same variable did it for me ` var realurl = "{{url(...)}}".replace('filename',data.image);, thank you for the help @newUserName02